# Django Admin models that appear in app section, but not on the admin home

Tags: django, django-admin

I've inherited some code that I need to add some new models (and admin models) to, and I've noticed a slight oddity.

There are several models within an app, that do not appear to the user on the admin interface on the app's section home page (the page you land on after logging in to the admin site), but that *do* appear on the app's *page* of admin site.  It seems that when I add a new model to the app, and register it to the admin site, it behaves in this way.

Is this a feature of Django's admin that I'm not familiar with, or do I need to hunt for some custom code that's controlling this?

To be clear, imagine an app (called 'app'), with 2 models (Model1, and Model2) registered in the admin interface.  You log into the admin site, and on the main page, you see the 'App' header, and underneath it, is only Model1.  You click on the 'App' header, the breadcrumb nav now says "Home > App", and on that page you then see *both* Model1 and Model2.  How has this been done? How can I configure it? Or is something broken?

Comment: There are apps that can alter the behavior of the admin site, and you can also override the templates yourself to show whatever you want. What does your `INSTALLED_APPS` look like? Do your app have an `admin` folder in the templates?

Comment: Thanks, there are templates in the admin folder, but none that look relevant to cause this.  Then looking at the INSTALLED_APPS, and quickly looking at what each of them do, I seem to have discovered the cause.  I will answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that in the INSTALLED_APPS there were several apps I wasn't familiar with, but two were called "grappelli" and "grappelli.dashboard".

Noticing furhter down in settings.py there was a setting:

```
GRAPPELLI_INDEX_DASHBOARD = "the_app.dashboard.AdminDashboard"
```

I found the AdminDashboard class and sure enough, in there, is a definition of what models appear on the 'dashboard' of the admin site.